# Custom Spinner with different background color for custom dropdown icon

Tags: android, android-spinner

Based on the requirement, I am trying to implement a custom spinner in my app. Please refer the below image:

[image]

What I have tried is :

```
  <Spinner
    android:layout_width="@dimen/quoteEntryDialogItemSpinnerWidth"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/spinner_style"
    />
```

In style.xml:

```
<style name="spinner_style" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#DFFFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

In drawable/gradient_spinner.xml:

```
<item><layer-list>
    <item><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#535353" android:centerColor="#484848" android:startColor="#323232" android:type="linear" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" android:topRightRadius="4dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"  />
    </shape></item>
    <item ><bitmap android:gravity="end" android:src="@drawable/spinner_arrow" />
    </item>
</layer-list></item>
```

All I am getting is a spinner with the same background similar to the dropdown icon.

The background of both the spinner and the icon has to be different. I am unable to achieve thi particular design. Most of the other designs have same background for both the spinner and the dropdown anchor. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you tried??

Comment: @PriteshVadhiya: wait I am updating my question

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `left` to the second item wrapping the `bitmap`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><layer-list>
        <item
            ><shape android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#535353" android:centerColor="#484848" android:startColor="#323232" android:type="linear" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" android:topRightRadius="4dp" />

            <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"  />
        </shape></item>
        <item
            android:left="130dp"
            >
            <bitmap  android:gravity="end" android:src="@drawable/spinner_arrow" />
        </item>
    </layer-list></item>
</selector>
```

That is if you still want to try to do this your way.

Another good option is to do like GAGAN suggested, which is to make a 9patch image where the arrow is of fixed size, and the left part is resizable.

Answer (score 0):

In spinner tag of your xml file,
set

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_dropdown"
```

and ic_dropdown can be your png file.

Comment: Actually I am trying to show separate background colours for the icon and spinner content part.

Comment: For setting background you can do the above.
For specific items,
if(mySpinner's current value == (item1||item4)) {

    mySpinner.setBackgroundColor(red);

}